# Can I do anything to make my gas oven better?

Tags: gas, oven

I am trying to bake bread, and the recipe calls for heating the oven at 500 degrees, but my oven can only reached 450- 460, can i do anything to make it reach higher temperatures ?

Comment: Is the oven shell rated to take 500 degree temperatures? The manufacturer very likely knows best on this one. What exactly is being baked that requires that high a temperature? Or is this only a preheat?

Comment: Its preheat temperature, and i am baking artisan sourdough bread,

Comment: Hmm, sounds like there's a need to upgrade to industry standard equipment built to take the heat then. You're trying to simulate a wood fired oven made of ceramic which will have some thermal mass to absorb and re-radiate the heat for that hard crust you're trying to achieve. The thin walls of a home kitchen oven don't have what it takes to be able to use a 500 degree preheat.

Comment: Have the burners been adjusted recently? Or cleaned? Cleaning and adjusting the burners may be all it needs, if it can be **set** to 500 but never reaches that temperature.

Comment: What are you using to measure temperature? When was it last calibrated? Does the oven have a 500° setting that's not being reached, or does the knob, or whatever, only go to 450°?

Answer (score 1):

Is it safe to make it reach higher temperatures? The oven will contain metals, chemical coatings, seals, glass, and so on, and therefor the construction of it may only be safe for a certain temperature. Over heating it may make the materials expand too much, damage the seals, and heat adjoining units and cause extra damage (worse case scenario = house fire). I would suggest cooking for little longer at lower temperatures.

Comment: +1. Find a recipe which works with your oven. Most bread recipes do NOT require 500 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Professional Grade FibraMent **Baking Stones** --[Breadtopia.com](http://www.breadtopia.com/store/baking-stones.html)

> The next best thing to a wood fired hearth oven for your breads and pizzas. Their high thermal mass **[3/4" thick]** and even heat transfer properties cannot be equaled with lighter, lesser quality pizza stones.

My parents keep theirs on the lower rack, whether it's 'being used' or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does your oven allow you to enter 500 as the target temperature?  If it allows this, and its not reaching this temperature then it might be an issue with the thermometer (it could also just be that you need to wait longer for it to heat up).  If the thermostat does not allow you to enter 500 degrees, then this would be a limitation of the oven.

I would strongly advise against trying to hack it into increasing the temperature as the oven probably isn't rated for higher temps and you could risk fire or serious injury.

You might have an easier time hitting those temperatures in a BBQ.

Comment: It only reaches to 450-460.

Answer (score 0):

If the oven has a self-cleaning cycle, that may reach higher temperatures. Of course that isn't very controllable, and the safety lock means you can't remove anything from the oven until it has cooled back down.

And your cookware may not be rated to those temperatures.

Comment: Self-cleaning, of course, is typically around 600 and is intended to burn rather than cook.